# Errors were encountered while processing: rtl8822ce-dkms rtl88x2ce-dkms Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

After typing the following command:

`sudo apt install mainline -y`

I'm getting the following error:

```
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up rtl8822ce-dkms (5.7.3~jammy5) ...
Removing old rtl8822ce-5.7.3~ppa DKMS files...
Deleting module rtl8822ce-5.7.3~ppa completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new rtl8822ce-5.7.3~ppa DKMS files...
Building for 5.19.0-38-generic
Building initial module for 5.19.0-38-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl8822ce-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8822ce/5.7.3~ppa/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl8822ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8822ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Setting up rtl88x2ce-dkms (35403) ...
Removing old rtl88x2ce-35403 DKMS files...
Deleting module rtl88x2ce-35403 completely from the DKMS tree.
Loading new rtl88x2ce-35403 DKMS files...
Building for 5.19.0-38-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.19.0-38-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/rtl88x2ce-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.19.0-38-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl88x2ce/35403/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package rtl88x2ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl88x2ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8822ce-dkms
 rtl88x2ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Version: Ubuntu 22.04